# Can't start mysql server on centos 6.9

Tags: mysql, centos

My OS is centos 6.9.

I updated the MySQL version from 5.1 to 5.5 and then it worked.
But after sshd restarted, I can't start the MySQL server.

I tried :

```
# service mysql start
```

Error message:

```
Starting MySQL.Logging to '/var/lib/mysql/host.err'.
200425 12:44:09 mysqld_safe Directory '/var/lib/mysql' for UNIX socket file don't exists.
ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/var/lib/mysql/host.pid).
```

/var/lib/mysql directory doesn't exist and I am not sure why it doesn't exist.

I've read many forum posts but I didn't solve this yet.

How can I solve this?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If /var/lib/mysql doesn't exist, that is extremely concerning. Is it on a different file system that is not mounted? If you are lucky, only the mount point is missing and the file system isn't mounted. If that is not the case, I can only hope you have a backup. :-(

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually, I am not good at centos. If you were I, how can you solve this? This question may be a bit absurd but expects to understand and please teach me.

Comment: If you just want a working version of MySQL or MariaDB (CentOS ship with MariaDB), you could do something like: rpm -e mysql-* mariadb-*; yum install mariadb-server;. You may have to manually work around some dependencies