# Install MySQL 5.1 on CentOS 6.9

Tags: mysql, centos

I updated etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo file like that ($release=$releasever -> $release=6).

```
...
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever -Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6$arch=$basearch&repo=os&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch
...
```

And then updated yum too.

```
# sudo yum update
(base) [root@host ~]# yum list updates
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
YumRepo Error: All mirror URLs are not using ftp, http[s] or file.
 Eg. </html>/
 * base: mirrors.cat.pdx.edu
 * centos-sclo-rh: repos.lax.layerhost.com
 * centos-sclo-sclo: mirrors.cat.pdx.edu
 * epel: mirrors.kernel.org
 * extras: mirrors.vcea.wsu.edu
 * remi-php73: mirror.sjc02.svwh.net
 * remi-safe: mirror.sjc02.svwh.net
 * updates: sjc.edge.kernel.org
```

then, I tried to install MySQL but it didn't work correctly.

```
    # yum install mysql-server
    ...
    --> Processing Dependency: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit) for package: rpm-libs-4.8.0-59.el6.x86_64
    Package db4 is obsoleted by libdb4, but obsoleting package does not provide for requirements
    ---> Package sqlite.x86_64 0:3.6.20-1.el6_7.2 will be installed
    --> Processing Conflict: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 conflicts filesystem < 3
    --> Finished Dependency Resolution
    Error: Package: rpm-4.8.0-59.el6.x86_64 (base)
               Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
               Available: db4-4.7.25-22.el6.x86_64 (base)
                   libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
    Error: Package: libdb4-utils-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
               Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
    Error: Package: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
               Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit)
    Error: Package: iproute-2.6.32-57.el6.x86_64 (base)
               Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
               Available: db4-4.7.25-22.el6.x86_64 (base)
                   libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
    Error: Package: pam-1.1.1-24.el6.x86_64 (base)
               Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
               Available: db4-4.7.25-22.el6.x86_64 (base)
                   libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
    Error: Package: rpm-libs-4.8.0-59.el6.x86_64 (base)
               Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
               Available: db4-4.7.25-22.el6.x86_64 (base)
                   libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
    Error: libdb4 conflicts with filesystem-2.4.30-3.el6.x86_64
    Error: Package: cyrus-sasl-lib-2.1.23-15.el6_6.2.x86_64 (base)
               Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
               Available: db4-4.7.25-22.el6.x86_64 (base)
                   libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
    Error: Package: 4:perl-5.10.1-144.el6.x86_64 (base)
               Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
               Available: db4-4.7.25-22.el6.x86_64 (base)
                   libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
     You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
     You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

How can I install MySQL on CentOS 6.9. Any version is ok.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you installing such an old version?

Comment: Thanks for your response. For me, any version is ok. At first, I installed MySQL 5.1 and it worked well. And before 1 week, I updated the version to 5.5 and it worked too. But after sshd restarted, MySQL didn't work. Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61447464/cant-start-mysql-server-on-centos-6-9).
I posted it but I can't solve it. How can I solve this problem.

Comment: `For me, any version is ok` Then try installing MySQL 8, surely....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error: Package: rpm-4.8.0-59.**el6**.x86_64 (base)
>
> Error: Package: libdb4-utils-4.8.30-13.**el7**.x86_64 (epel)

You are obviously mixing EL6 and EL7 packages.

Fix your installation by installing the proper EPEL configuration package.

BTW, CentOS 6 is close to its end of life (in November) so I heartily recommend using a more modern version.

Comment: Good call on informing folks that CentOS 6 is ending its life.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I typed following command. `sudo yum install epel-release` and then typed  `sudo yum update`, then typed MySQL installation command but it's the same result. How can I install the proper EPEL configuration package.

Comment: You need  https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm

Comment: I tried `sudo yum install epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm`.
Error messages are like that.

`Loaded plugins: fastestmirror

Setting up Install Process

Examining epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm: epel-release-6-8.noarch

epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm: does not update installed package.

Error: Nothing to do`

Comment: Should I need to remove the `epel-release-6-8.noarch` before?

Comment: You have to remove epel-release (which is obviously v7) or downgrade to 6.8 one

Comment: I removed 6.8 and install 6, so I have installed MySQL. It is installed correctly(no error happened). After that, I tried to start MySQL but the error like below happened. 
 `ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!
Starting MySQL...... ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/var/lib/mysql/host.pid). `
I have read many posts in forums but until now, I can't solve it.